# passing php variables through header

Tags: php, redirect, header

I want to pass a variable through header. In my system the user stays on the profile page and click on a link to fill and submit a form. When the form is submitted the page redirect to the profile page. When I the profile page displayed the member id has lost, so it don't display the member details. What I want to do is pass the member id when redirecting happens.

```
function redirect_to($location = NULL){
    if($location != NULL){
        header("Location:{$location}");
        exit;
    }
}


redirect_to('member_profile.php');
```

what I am trying to do is this

```
redirect_to('member_profile.php?id=$mselcted_memberI');
```

Comment: And why can't you do what you're trying to do? Did you try using `"` instead of `'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes `'` which will make it a literal string, instead, concatenate that using a `.` instead

```
redirect_to('member_profile.php?id='.$mselcted_memberI);
```

Also, you don't require braces `{}` here

```
header("Location:$location");
```

Comment: @user3138830 than you are doing something weird

Comment: Braces make code more readable. I always use braces when placing vars into strings.

Comment: @Jari Depends, I only use them when dealing with arrays `$var['blah']`